# read 4 lines after specific delimiter encountered c++

Tags: c++

I've been trying to create simple program, that can works as cash register. It is suppose to read from a file the followings: 
- name, 
- price, 
- tells if its fruit or vegetable ,
- calories

In my opinion the best way would be to detect identify number (something like barcode) and then read 4 lines and get 4 strings after ":" delimiter.

Here is the txt file that i've created:

```
# Vegetables #

Iden number             :   11
Name                    :   Carrot
Price       [zl/kg]     :   2
Group                   :   Vegetable
Calories    [cal/100 g] :   33

Nr Iden                 :   12
Name                    :   Tomato
Price       [zl/kg]     :   4
Group                   :   Vegetable
Calories    [cal/100 g] :   20

Iden number             :   13
Name                    :   Cucumber
Price       [zl/kg]     :   1
Group                   :   Vegetable
Calories    [cal/100 g] :   14

# Fruits #

Iden number             :   21
Name                    :   Apple
Price       [zl/kg]     :   2
Group                   :   Fruit
Calories    [cal/100 g] :   52

Iden number             :   22
Name                    :   Orange
Price       [zl/kg]     :   4
Group                   :   Fruit
Calories    [cal/100 g] :   47

Iden number             :   23
Name                    :   Kiwi
Price       [zl/kg]     :   1
Group                   :   Fruit
Calories    [cal/100 g] :   60
```

Here is the code that detect delimiters and ignore empty lines or the one that starts with "#". But i don't know how to read only 4 following lines after detected identy_number.

```
    int main()
{
  string line;
  ifstream plik ("baza_danych_produktow.txt");
  if (plik.is_open())
  {
    while ( getline (plik,line) )
    {
    line.erase(std::remove_if(line.begin(), line.end(), ::isspace),line.end());

     if(line[0] == '#' || line.empty()){ // if line starts with # or is empty - ignore
            continue;
        }

    auto delimiterPos = line.find(":");
    auto name = line.substr(0, delimiterPos);
    std::string value = line.substr(delimiterPos + 1);
    cout << value;
    cout << endl;
    }
    plik.close();
  }

  else cout << "Unable to open file";

  return 0;
}
```

My code display every string after ":" delimiter in every single line of file that is not empty or do not start with "#".

Here is the output:

```
11
Carrot
2
Vegetable
33
12
Tomato
4
Vegetable
20
13
Cucumber
1
Vegetable
13
21
Apple
2
Fruit
52
22
Orange
4
Fruit
47
23
Kiwi
1
Fruit
60
```

Could you please help me with that, so the output for example **input: 11** would look like this?

```
Carrot
2
Vegetable
33
```

Best regards.

Comment: You could call another `getline` 4 times inside the while loop if you found the id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could call another getline 4 times inside the while loop if you found the id

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::stringstream;
using std::string;

int main()
{
    string id = "22";
    string line;

    stringstream plik ("# Vegetables #\n\nIden number             :   11\nName                    :   Carrot\nPrice       [zl/kg]     :   2\nGroup                   :   Vegetable\nCalories    [cal/100 g] :   33\n\nNr Iden                 :   12\nName                    :   Tomato\nPrice       [zl/kg]     :   4\nGroup                   :   Vegetable\nCalories    [cal/100 g] :   20\n\nIden number             :   13\nName                    :   Cucumber\nPrice       [zl/kg]     :   1\nGroup                   :   Vegetable\nCalories    [cal/100 g] :   14\n\n# Fruits #\n\nIden number             :   21\nName                    :   Apple\nPrice       [zl/kg]     :   2\nGroup                   :   Fruit\nCalories    [cal/100 g] :   52\n\nIden number             :   22\nName                    :   Orange\nPrice       [zl/kg]     :   4\nGroup                   :   Fruit\nCalories    [cal/100 g] :   47\n\nIden number             :   23\nName                    :   Kiwi\nPrice       [zl/kg]     :   1\nGroup                   :   Fruit\nCalories    [cal/100 g] :   60\n");

    if (/*plik.is_open()*/ true) {
        while (getline(plik, line)) {
            line.erase(std::remove_if(line.begin(), line.end(), ::isspace), line.end());

            if (line[0] == '#' || line.empty()) { // if line starts with # or is empty - ignore
                continue;
            }

            auto delimiterPos = line.find(":");
            auto name = line.substr(0, delimiterPos);
            if (name == "Idennumber") {
                std::string currentId = line.substr(delimiterPos + 1);
                for (unsigned short i{ 0 }; i < 4; ++i) {
                    getline(plik, line);
                    auto delimiterPos = line.find(":");
                    auto name = line.substr(0, delimiterPos);
                    std::string value = line.substr(delimiterPos + 1);

                    if (currentId == id) {
                        cout << value << '\n';
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        /*plik.close();*/
    }
    else
        cout << "Unable to open file";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: One more question. What if chosen id do not appear inside of a file? How to detect the lack of it?

Comment: @kabanos Use a boolean flag

Answer (score 0):

I would like to present to you a more "modern" C++ - solution. Using algorithms and a "more" OO (object oriented) approach.

In my humble opinion, the key to object oriented design is, to put data and their methods together in an object (class).

For example a product has some data members. And it has the wisdom how to and the responsibility to read and write its data. So no third party should read/write the data from/into such an object.

If you follow this approach, then you can read a complete product record with `fileStream >> product;`. That's it. a one liner. And more intuitive

Same with printing. As you do with printing a number via `std::cout << number;` you would do the same with a product. Why not write `std::cout << product`.

In the below code, I added a function test, which does exactly that. This is extremely simple.

Additionally I read all data in memory, to give you a more comprehensive example. The code has tons of comments and should be easy to understand.

Please see:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

// This is a file. It is the same as reading a file from a disk
std::istringstream inputFile{ R"(# Vegetables #

Iden number : 11
Name : Carrot
Price[zl / kg] : 2
Group : Vegetable
Calories[cal / 100 g] : 33

Nr Iden : 12
Name : Tomato
Price[zl / kg] : 4
Group : Vegetable
Calories[cal / 100 g] : 20

Iden number : 13
Name : Cucumber
Price[zl / kg] : 1
Group : Vegetable
Calories[cal / 100 g] : 14

# Fruits #

Iden number : 21
Name : Apple
Price[zl / kg] : 2
Group : Fruit
Calories[cal / 100 g] : 52

Iden number : 22
Name : Orange
Price[zl / kg] : 4
Group : Fruit
Calories[cal / 100 g] : 47

Iden number : 23
Name : Kiwi
Price[zl / kg] : 1
Group : Fruit
Calories[cal / 100 g] : 60
)" };

// Create Some shorter name
constexpr std::string::size_type NOK = std::string::npos;
// This is, what we are searching for in the product data
const std::vector<std::string_view> identifier{ "Name","Price","Group","Calories" };

// Our product class. Keep data and methods together in on object
struct Product
{
    Product() : data(identifier.size()) {}
    // The iden number
    std::string iden{};
    // All data. Since verything is treated as a string, we will put this in a vector
    std::vector<std::string> data;

    // This class knows how to read and write its data. This is the know how of this objec´t. It belongs to here.
    // Overwrite extractor operator >>
    friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, Product& p);
    // Overwrite inserter operator <<
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const Product& p);

};

// The inserter operator for a product. Very simple. Print all available data
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const Product& p)
{
    // First the iden number
    os << "\n" << std::left << std::setw(15) << "Iden number" << p.iden << '\n';
    // And then all data
    for (size_t index = 0U; (index < p.data.size()) && (index < identifier.size()); ++index) 
        os << std::setw(15) << identifier[index] << p.data[index] << '\n';
    return os;
}

// The products extractor operator. That is a little bit more complex
std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, Product& p)
{
    std::string line{};
    size_t pos{ 0 }; size_t index{ 0 }; 

    // We will read lines from the input stream, until we are done
    while (getline(is, line)) {
        // First, search for a string that conatins "Iden" or "Nr Iden"
        pos = line.find(':'); // Look if the line has a double colon
        // Search
        if (((line.find("Iden") == 0) || line.find("Nr Iden" == 0)) && (pos != NOK)) {

            // Ok, we found a line that contains "Iden" or "Nr Iden" 
            std::istringstream iss(line.substr(pos + 1));
            iss >> p.iden; // Read the data into our product internal variable

            // Now continue to read lines. Either 4 lines or until some read error
            while ((index < identifier.size()) && getline(is, line)) {
                // Check the position of the double colon
                pos = line.find(":");
                // And now find the expected search string given in identifier{ "Name","Price","Group","Calories" }
                if ((line.find(identifier[index]) != NOK) && (pos != NOK)) {
                    // if Foundm, then put the data into our product internal data variable
                    std::istringstream iss(line.substr(pos + 1));
                    iss >> p.data[index];
                }
                ++index;
            }
            break;  // After we read on product, we will stop reading lines
        }
        // else, if the line does not match our expected value, then ignore it and read next line
    }
    return is;
 }


void test()
{
    Product product{};
    // What we want to show
    std::string searchID{ "22" };
    // Read all products
    while (inputFile >> product) {

        // If we found what we were looking for 
        if (product.iden == searchID) {
            // Then show result
            std::cout << product << "\n\n";
            break; // stop further reading
        }
    }
}


 int main()
 {
     test(); inputFile.seekg(0);;

     // Define variable that holds all products
     // Define variable with range constructor that will copy the data from somewhere begin to somewhere end
     // Somewhere begin is the istream iterator that reads from the beginning of the file
     // Somewhere end is the istream iterator that reads until end of file
     // Since the extractor operator >> of the product has been overwritten, the istream_iteratir will call this operatir with the istream
     std::vector<Product> products{std::istream_iterator<Product>(inputFile), std::istream_iterator<Product>() };

     // For debug purposes. Print all products
     std::cout << "\nThis is the complete list of products that we have read from the file:\n\n";
     // We use the copy operator. Meaning, we copy the range products.begin/products.end to somewhere
     // The somewhere is the std ostream_iterator which will simple print the given data to std::cout
     // Since we have overwritten the inserter operator << of the product, this operator will be called for each element in the products list
     std::copy(products.begin(), products.end(), std::ostream_iterator<Product>(std::cout, "\n"));

     // Ask the user, what product he wants to see
     std::cout << "\n\nWhat product do you want to see? Enter Iden number:  ";
     std::string searchString{};
     // Get that value from the user
     std::cin >> searchString;

     // And now find it in the list of products. All product in the products list will be check. Their iden will be compared with the search string
     std::vector<Product>::iterator iter = std::find_if(products.begin(), products.end(), [&searchString](const Product & p) { return p.iden == searchString; });

     // If we could find something
     if (iter != products.end()) 
         // Show some text and the data. We show the data be inserting *iter in the std::cout stream. The will call the product inserter operator
         std::cout << "\n\nFound product with Iden (" << searchString << ")   -->\n" << *iter << '\n';
      else
         // Nothing could be found
         std::cout << "\n\nProduct with Iden (" << searchString << ")  NOT found in proct list\n";

     return 0;
 }
```

Please see the how simple the "test" function is. And, if you make changes to the product, it will still work. Because the functionality is hidden in the product, where it belongs to. It is encapsulated.